# working of ndim in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.ndim
1
```

How the dimension is 1 .I have given a equation of 3 variables it means it is a 3 dimension but it is showing the dimension as 1 . Can anyone tell me the logic of ndim?

Comment: >>> a=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,3,6,4],[2,3,1,4]])
>>> a.ndim
2
for this i have give 3 vectors then it should show 3 dimensions

Comment: It sounds like you have confused `a.dim` with `a.size`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [working of ndim in numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979443/working-of-ndim-in-numpy)

Answer (score 1):

You have created an array with four elements.  That is, a vector.  It has one dimension, as NumPy says.

Comment: >>> a=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,3,6,4],[2,3,1,4]]) >>> a.ndim 2 for this i have give 3 vectors then it should show 3 dimensions

Comment: @RobinMandela: if you `print a` you will clearly see that is a 2D array: its dimensions are 3x4 (or 4x3 if you prefer).  I think you want `a.shape` instead, which gives you `(3,4)`, so `a.shape[0]` gives you the `3` you desire.  Note `len(a)` does as well.

Comment: np.array([[[1,2,3]]]).ndim , it gives 3!