# What is the real working of ndim in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

Consider:

```
import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.ndim
1
```

How is the dimension 1? I have given a equation of three variables. It means it is three-dimensional, but it is showing the dimension as 1. What is the logic of ndim?

Comment: To give you the idea of how 2-dim is: try `np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]).ndim`, maybe you are looking for `a.shape`.

Answer (score 5):

As the [NumPy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) says, `numpy.ndim(a)` returns:

> The number of dimensions in `a`.  Scalars are zero-dimensional

E.g.:

```
a = np.array(111)
b = np.array([1,2])
c = np.array([[1,2], [4,5]])
d = np.array([[1,2,3,], [4,5]])
print a.ndim, b.ndim, c.ndim, d.ndim
#outputs: 0 1 2 1
```

Note that the last array, `d`, is an array of *object* `dtype`, so its dimension is still `1`.

What you want to use could be `a.shape` (or `a.size` for a one-dimensional array):

```
print a.size, b.size
print c.size # == 4, which is the total number of elements in the array
# Outputs:
1 2
4
```

Method `.shape` returns you a `tuple`, and you should get your *dimension* using `[0]`:

```
print a.shape, b.shape, b.shape[0]
() (2L,) 2
```